# Why does in C++ big endian to int16 with bitshift not work?

Tags: c++, qt, endianness, bit-shift

I'm reading a bytearray (2 byte big endian) with Qt

```
QByteArray a = data.mid(cellNumber, 2);
int16 res = qFromBigEndian<qint16>(a);
```

and want ot get int16. It works correctly but slow.

If I use

```
std::bitset<16> b0(a[0]);
std::bitset<16> b1(a[1]);
qint16 b = (b0 << 8) | (b1 << 0);
```

the result is wrong. The reason is the following:

```
00000001 a0
10101011 a1

00000000 00000001 b0 correct
11111111 10101011 b1 not correct, why does it fill with 1? (should be 00000000 10101011)
-----------------
11111111 10101011 wrong!
00000001 10101011 this would be correct
```

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `QByteArray`'s `[]` operator uses signed `char`, `10101011` is a negative number, calling shift left on a negaative number is undefined bahaviour

Comment: @AlanBirtles Unless C++20 is used, right?

Comment: @AlanBirtles: BTW, shift left is used on class, not on signed integral.

Comment: I don't see how using class `std::bitset` would be more performant than `qFromBigEndian`

Comment: @Jarod42: You are right, it's not faster as with Qt qFromBigEndian!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thxs to All!!!

```
std::bitset<16> b0(static_cast<unsigned char>(a[cellNumber]));
std::bitset<16> b1(static_cast<unsigned char>(a[cellNumber + 1]));
std::bitset<16> resb = (b0 << 8) | (b1 << 0);
int16_t resi = int16_t(resb.to_ulong());
```

I tested it also for negativ values, as long they of course don't exceed the int limits.

Answer (score 1):

`bitset` take `unsigned long long` whereas `QByteArray::operator[]` return `char`, `signed` in your case.

And you have integral promotion, making negative number as big number (filled with 1).

Possible solution

```
std::bitset<16> b0(static_cast<unsigned char>(a[0]));
std::bitset<16> b1(static_cast<unsigned char>(a[1]));
```